# Submitting a form with Ajax generated by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to get this ajax working, but it doesn't return anything! I've tried working it out for quite a while but I'm stumped. I get no return whatsoever.

I'm using PHP to generate the HTML and Ajax below, so here is the output of the script producing the Ajax that doesn't work.

```
<div id='imageOptionsDiv1' name='imageOptionsDiv1'>

  <p>Convert This Image</p>
  <p>Specify Filename: <input type="text" id='userphotofilename1' name='userphotofilename1' value='HonestRepairSmallLogo_png'>

  <select id='photoextension1' name='photoextension1'>
    <option value="">Select Format</option>
    <option value="jpg">Jpg</option>
    <option value="bmp">Bmp</option>
    <option value="png">Png</option>
  </select></p>

  <p>Width and height: </p>
  <p><input type="number" size="4" value="0" id='width1' name='width1' min="0" max="10000"> X <input type="number" size="4" value="0" id="height1" name="height1" min="0"  max="10000"></p> 
  <p>Rotate: <input type="number" size="3" id='rotate1' name='rotate1' value="0" min="0" max="359"></p>
  <input type="submit" id='convertPhotoSubmit1' name='convertPhotoSubmit1' value='Convert Image'>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#convertPhotoSubmit1').click(function() {
      var rot = $('rotate1').val();
      var wid = $('width1').val();
      var hgt = $('height1').val();
      var pext = $('photoextension1').val;
      var upfn = $('userphotofilename1').val;

      $.ajax({
        url: 'convertCore.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          rotate:rot,
          width:wid,
          height:hgt,
          photoextension:pext,
          userphotofilename:upfn},
          success: function(data) {
            alert("convertGui2.php"); },
          error: function(data) {
            alert("Cannot convert this file!"); }
      });
    });
  });
  </script>

</div>
```

As requested, here is the section of PHP that generates the above code....

```
    if (in_array($extension, $ImageArray1)) {
    ?>
    <div id='imageOptionsDiv<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>' name='imageOptionsDiv<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>' style="max-width:750px; display:none;">
      <p style="max-width:1000px;"></p>
      <p>Convert This Image</p>
      <p>Specify Filename: <input type="text" id='userphotofilename<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>' name='userphotofilename<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>' value='<?php echo str_replace('.', '_', $File); ?>'>
      <select id='photoextension<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>' name='photoextension<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>'>
        <option value="">Select Format</option>
        <option value="jpg">Jpg</option>
        <option value="bmp">Bmp</option>
        <option value="png">Png</option>
      </select></p>
      <p>Width and height: </p>
      <p><input type="number" size="4" value="0" id='width<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>' name='width<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>' min="0" max="10000"> X <input type="number" size="4" value="0" id="height<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>" name="height<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>" min="0"  max="10000"></p> 
      <p>Rotate: <input type="number" size="3" id='rotate<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>' name='rotate<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>' value="0" min="0" max="359"></p>
      <input type="submit" id='convertPhotoSubmit<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>' name='convertPhotoSubmit<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>' value='Convert Image' onclick="toggle_visibility('loadingCommandDiv');">

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#convertPhotoSubmit<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>').click(function() {
          var rot = $('#rotate<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>').val();
          var wid = $('#width<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>').val();
          var hgt = $('#height<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>').val();
          var pext = $('#photoextension<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>').val;
          var upfn = $('#userphotofilename<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>').val;
          $.ajax({
            url: 'convertCore.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              rotate:rot,
              width:wid,
              height:hgt,
              photoextension:pext,
              userphotofilename:upfn},
              success: function(data) {
                alert("convertGui2.php"); },
              error: function(data) {
                alert("Cannot convert this file!"); }
          });
        });
      });
      </script>

    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <?php } ?>
</div>

<?php
include ('footer.php');
?>
```

The posts need to go to convertCore.php which contains a bunch of spaghetti that converts files with command line tools. There is no incrementer on the internal PHP script. The increments are only needed to distinguish different GUI elements on the page. An older version of the project can be seen at https://github.com/zelon88/HRConvert2

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @zelon88 - better option to use serialize to collect form data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557644/how-to-access-php-super-global-post-variable-after-ajax-request?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I found one and realized that I had a 404 on my jQuery include. However there are still errors. The error I'm getting now is...  jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at val (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)
    at e (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)
    at xb (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)
    at Function.r.param (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (convertCore.php?showFiles=1:133)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't return anything because jQuery doesn't know what this `$('rotate1').val();` is relating to...

If it's the id you are getting here, then you need to put the id symbol `#` infront of the id. Like so...

```
$('#rotate1').val();
```

Likewise if it's the name attribute you're trying to get, try using this...

```
$('input[name="rotate1"]').val();
```

Put the relevant tag for each one; select, input, etc.

**Update**

Make sure that in your Ajax data call, you are setting the correct key in the key:value pairs. The key should reflect the name attribute of the elements as this is where we exchange information with php.

So in the data argument of Ajax, the pairs should look like:

```
rotate1:rot, 
width1:wid, 
height1:hgt, 
photoextension1:pext,
userphotofilename1:upfn
```

Comment: It's the name, so you use https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Doesn't have to be the name... we're just getting the values so it could be any identifier...

Comment: I did this and fixes another issue and now I'm getting errors. It still progress though, so we're on the right track! See my comment in the post above for the error message.

Comment: Ok. Make sure you set the exact same name in the Ajax data as it is on the element. I can see that `rotate:rot` should be `rotate1:rot`. This is where we specify the name attributes to pass on to the php. I shall update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. In the PHP page though the inputs don't have the increment number, so I think that part is ok. What I get now is jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at val (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)
    at e (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)
    at xb (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)
    at Function.r.param (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (convertCore.php?showFiles=1:133)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:3)

Comment: Well, either way the name in the php as well as in html and Ajax call have to be exactly the same and correlate to one another. Please can you update your question to include the php code.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question to elaborate a little more.

Comment: I've read your updated question. However, this is still a name attribute issue. If you only increment for identifying reasons then just using the id alone is enough, since this has to be unique. So don't increment the name at all, but remember to change/delete the increments everywhere where you use the name.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is take the input elements from photoOptionsDiv1 and submit it to convertCore.php without the increment (because the internal functions don't care about increment). The increment on the front end needs to exist so when a user clicks photoOptionsDiv2 (the second image on the page) the hidden div for photoOptionsDiv1 doesn't appear. The Ajax is supposed to take the inputs from photoOption# and submit it to convertCore.php as photoOption.

Comment: The div elements in the gui are created in a for loop with PHP, hence why they are incremented (so the Jscript can be targeted to each iteration of the element on the page). The back-end PHP doesn't care what NUMBER the photoOption is because the Ajax is supposed to pass along the value in a POST request.

Comment: Yes. But I don't think you understand the relationship between the passed values and the name attribute. The name is the only identifier php can access with $_POST. This has to be the same throughout all html, scripts and php, exacting to every letter and number. Therefore if you pass a value through as the name rotate1 but php only handles rotate, then it won't know what to do with it. I suggest you read up on general php form submission and the docs for Ajax.

Comment: Well, I figured it out with the second example from your comment. I am getting the name now instead of the id. I really appreciate all your time. Here was the fix... 
    $('input[name="rotate<?php echo $ConvertGuiCounter1; ?>"]').val(),